# Can Credit Card Numbers contain leading zeros?

Tags: database-design, credit-card

Often I have stored credit card numbers in `varchar(16)`. That works, but it takes 17 bytes per number.

Storage is not that big a deal, but I like to be efficient, for both storage requirement, and table search time.

If I could use `decimal(16) unsigned`, I could cut the storage requirement to 7 or 8 bytes, and still preserve readability as well as much of the compatibility.

This would strip leading zeros. Can I depend on all credit card numbers starting with a non-zero number?

Comment: Are the credit cards always 16 digits? Just pad-left with zeroes if so.

Comment: Are you storing billions of credit card numbers for this to make a difference, then also you are PCI DSS compliant yet do not know the answer to this question? I'd just say wow, that you can do this in only a varchar. Encryption algorithms must have come on a long way!

Comment: @tenfour: Not always. Sometimes they are 15 digits.

Comment: I'd say "efficiency" is not exactly what you want when storing credit card numbers.  You want encryption.  Which leads to the next thing, I can not envision a system that you would honestly want to be able to search through the entire credit card number.  Last 4? possibly, but not the whole thing.  This screams failure in every possible way.

Comment: Security should be your primary concern not size. **You shouldn't store credit card information without encryption**. consider [AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html), also read [using mySQL to store credit card info](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?30,14020,31632)

Comment: @tenfour: Uh, no. Leading zeroes are significant (in other words, credit card numbers are *not* integers), and the length can be 13+ digits.

Comment: @Tuga: You shouldn't be storing credit card numbers *at all*, if you can help it, but that's slightly off-topic ;)

Comment: @Piskvor: couldn't agree more, but if you've to store it at least encrypt it.

Comment: @Tuga: I'm not really in disagreement - if you're storing card numbers, you need to achieve PCI DSS compliance, which includes, but is not limited to, encryption. (obligatory: IANAL, and YMMV in different countries)

Comment: Lol at how this was closed off because it's "off topic".  This is a great question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number), the first digit can indeed be 0:

> The first digit of a credit card number is the Major Industry Identifier (MII), which represents the category of entity which issued the credit card. Different MII digits represent the following issuer categories:
>
> - 0 – ISO/TC 68 and other future industry assignments
> - etc.

So no, I don't think you'd want to use storage that omits leading zeros.

Answer (score 13):

Credit card numbers (like phone numbers and postal codes) are not numeric and should never be stored in a numeric datatype. They are inherently string data. Numbers that are not intended to be used in mathematical calculations (except autoassigned integers that are used as ids) are string data, they will be used as string data, they will be queried as string data.

Comment: What if I always add "1" to the card number and store it that way? I could keep it in integer type big enough (like uint64_t in c++, for example) and then if I'd like to compare two card numbers, it'd be much less expensive operation.

Comment: SInce credit card numbers should always be encrypted, comparing them is something you should never be doing. Store them as some sort fo character data type and encrypt them.

Comment: My application is meant to use credit cards that way (unencrypted), it must efficiently search for BIN numbers of credit cards, so it will perform a lot of comparisons. My question is: what solution will be more efficient, and not necessarily more secure? (:

Answer (score 3):

Only [ISO/TC 68 credit cards](http://www.merriampark.com/anatomycc.htm) start with leading zeros (see also the Wikipedia entry for [ISO/IEC 7812](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7812)). So it seems that they'd be very rare, but possibly existing