# Is there a number type with bigger capacity than u_long/UInt64 in Swift?

Tags: swift

Is there a type with bigger capacity than *u_long* or *UInt64* in Swift?

I have a function that takes very big integers to identify a credit card number with 28 digits:

```
func myFunc(number : /*What to put here?*/) {
    //body
}
```

what type is appropriate? should *number* be treated as a string?

Comment: it is possible to implement your own UInt128 type. or you can use NSDecimalNumber

Comment: How to implement UInt128?

Comment: just like how UInt64 implemented. make a struct, conform to protocols, implement necessary methods and operators

Comment: Could you please put it in an answer?

Comment: @user2864740 division and modulo by ten, plus `Int(ceil(log10(Double(number))))` to get its length (in digits)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A credit card number is *not* a number in a meaningful mathematical sense. It is a sequence of digits and *a CC should be treated as text*, much like a phone number. One immediate issue of using a fixed-length integer value is that code *cannot simultaneously detect [leading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7164969/2864740) and trailing zeros* from "no more numbers present".

Use a string or a specific (custom) type representing the CC number, probably using a string internally. The length of the number (in base-10) is then trivially the number of digits: which is the length of the underlying string.

The CC number (represented by a bonafide string) can later be *encoded* into an appropriate binary representation, if (and when) required.

Comment: great answer! converting to a any numeric type would have the problem with leading zeros which is significant in credit card numbers. Thanks

Comment: @Carpsen90 That being said, I've never seen such a number myself - but it's about representing the data for what it is.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement your own `UInt128` type. Or use `NSDecimalNumber`

To implement `UInt128`

```
struct UInt128 {
    var low : UInt64 = 0;
    var high : UInt64 = 0;
}
```

and you can implement operators

```
infix func + (l: UInt128, r: UInt128) -> UInt128 {
    // do your work... care with overflow 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a BigNumber library with which you can do some big number calculations. Actually the library is based on the GNU Multiple Precision (GMP) library (see: https://gmplib.org) and I wrote an Objective-C / Swift wrapper. Currently big integer mathematics, including a lot of operator overloading, is possible. A code example goes like:

```
var err : NSError?
var bi1 = BigInt(nr: 12468642135797531)
var bi2 = BigInt(nr: "12345678901011121314151617181920", error: &err)
var res = bi1 * bi2
println("Multiply 2 BigInts: bi1 * bi2 = \(res.toString())")
```

which results in:

```
Multiply 2 BigInts: bi1 * bi2 = 153933852140173822960829726365674325601913839520
```

You can find the library at: https://github.com/githotto/osxgmp

I think its fairly easy to do some 'credit-card-number' math with even numbers having far more than 28-digits.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to work with strings, and  define the mathematical operators to operate on strings also:

```
func +(lhs: String, rhs: Int8) -> String
func +(lhs: String, rhs: Int16) -> String
func +(lhs: String, rhs: Int32) -> String
func +(lhs: String, rhs: Int64) -> String
func +(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> String
// ... other operators
```

This has the advantage of theoretically allowing and unlimited number of digits, but has the disadvantage of the fact that the strings might not always represent numbers.