# How can I declare and initialize a constant bigger than UInt64 in Swift?

Tags: swift

I like to know, How can I declare and initialize a constant bigger than UInt64 in Swift?
Swift infer seems unable to work for down number. How I should solve this issue?

```
let number = 11111111222222233333333344444445555555987654321 // Error: overflow
print(number, type(of: number))
```

Comment: You can probably use a [Decimal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25614324/1187415

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigInteger equivalent in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531914/biginteger-equivalent-in-swift)

Comment: thanks for help @user28434 that does not helped me!

Comment: How ever the problem is much bigger! I think this question has no answer in swift! otherwise I build a giant number Type

Comment: The linked case from user28434 seems exactly this question. Can you explain why this question is different? Otherwise I'd like to dupe to that one.

Comment: because that use C, I am using Swift, as i maintained "in Swift"

Answer (score 3):

`Decimal` is the numeric type capable of holding the largest value in Swift. However,you can't declare a `Decimal` literal, since integer literals are inferred to `Int`, while floating point literals are inferred to `Double`, so you need to initialise the `Decimal` from a `String` literal.

```
let number = Decimal(string: "321321321155564654646546546546554653334334")!
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber) of `NSDecimalNumber` (whose Swift version is `Decimal` and hence their numeric range is equivalent):

> An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa x 10^exponent where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and exponent is an integer from –128 through 127.

If you need to be able to represent arbitrary-length numbers in Swift, you need to use a 3rd party library (or create one yourself), there's no built-in type that could handle this in Swift.

Comment: I tried your given code: the result is not correct. 11111111222222233333333344444445555555900000000 NSDecimal

Comment: @Omid how did you get that? If I print the result I do get the correct number (as expected)

Comment: @Omid that number cannot be represented as a `Decimal`, since it overflows even `Decimal`. `Decimal` can only have 38 leading digits that are non-zero, and the `Decimal(string:)` init seems to keep exactly that many digits, then just initializes the remaining digits as 0. If you need that many digits, you'll need to use a 3rd party library that can represent arbitrary-length numbers in Swift.